# Hidden div value, how to do this?

Tags: html

Hello I'm trying to make the following:

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass" myownattributehere="somevalue">hellooooo</div>
```

Is it possible to create a hidden attribute in a div like such, "myownattributehere" or is there another way to do this?

I've heard of putting anchors in to do this? Simple or can it be done via div only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML5's `data` attribute.

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass" data-myownattributehere="somevalue">hellooooo</div>
```

Comment: develop a bit, you can use jQuery's `.data('myownattributehere'[, newValue])` as getter/setter and add documentation reference

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `data-my-own-attribute-here="..."`.
2. Make sure to have HTML5 DOCTYPE: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`
3. In JavaScript, you can access it like this: `document.getElementById('myid').getAttribute('data-my-own-attribute-here')`.
4. Or in jQuery, access it like: `$('myid').data('myOwnAttributeHere')`.

See also [HTML5 data attributes](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Use html5 data attributes:

```
<div data-your_attribute_name="value"></data>
```

You can do this on almost any DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If "SEO" is not important for you, you can use like this. But it wil not be a valid usage in w3c validatain process. Also after using like this you can "get" or "set" this attribute via jQuery

```
...
$("#myid").attr("myownattributehere");// get
...
$("#myid").attr({"myownattributehere": "somevalue"});// set
```